# How to retrieve available branches from a Bitbucket repository?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

It is possible to retrieve the local branches from a local repository with `hg branches`. Is it possible to do this also with a remote repository programatically?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought the answer was “it's right there on the project's overview page”, but perhaps you're asking about something more specific.

Comment: I would like to retrive it programmatically with the hg command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to determine the branches in a remote Mercurial repository without pulling in the repository.  You can avoid saving data on disk, by getting the information you desire by using `hg incoming`, but that command works by pulling the entire repository data anyway--likely not what you want.  Unfortunately, your best bet is probably going to be simply to perform a check-out, and then query your now-local repository.

If that's truly unacceptable, you have two additional solutions: you can screen-scape the Bitbucket page for your repository, using a tool like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), or you can wait until Bitbucket releases their API, which will likely provide this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Use bitbucket API

curl http://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/:username/:repo_slug/branches/

Read more here: http://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/doc/repositories/